# MYSQL: Merge/combine two records set from group by result

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am trying build a Product picklist for orders, so in large order system vendor can easily prepare their orders.

Have three general tables (orders, order_products, order_options).

here is my query and results

```
SELECT op.order_id ,  op.name, op.product_id, op.order_product_id, op.quantity,  
GROUP_CONCAT(oo.product_option_id SEPARATOR ',') as option_ids, GROUP_CONCAT(oo.product_option_value_id SEPARATOR ',') as value_ids
FROM `o2oeco_order_product` AS op LEFT JOIN `o2oeco_order_option` AS oo ON oo.order_product_id = op.order_product_id
WHERE op.order_id IN (380,381) 
GROUP BY op.product_id,oo.order_product_id
ORDER BY `order_product_id`  DESC
```

---

```
orderid name    product_id  order_product_id quantity   option_ids  value_ids   
381     sample pr   207     540     6   NULL    NULL
381     sample pr   219     539     1   308     228
381     sample p    219     538     2   308     227
381     079c1477    221     537     2   367,368,338     340,341,298
381     079c1477    221     536     3   367,368,338     339,342,283
380     e7181331    212     535     3   NULL    NULL
380     Sample p    198     534     1   NULL    NULL
380     079c1477    221     533     1   367,368,338     339,342,283
380     079c1477    221     532     2   367,368,338     340,342,298
380     079c1477    221     531     1   338,367,368     283,340,341
380     079c1477    221     530     1   367,368,338     340,341,324
380     079c1477    221     529     1   367,368,338     340,341,298
```

---

Now i want to merge/combine or group by (not sure) result based on product_id & product_option so same product with same option value can be merged together to easily pick same physical product

[image]

What I need to merge above result (4th row and 12th row should be merged) and quantity should be 3 (2+1) for 4th row, actually I want combine quantity for same product with same option values.

---

```
orderid name    product_id  order_product_id quantity   option_ids  value_ids   
381     sample pr   207     540     6   NULL    NULL
381     sample pr   219     539     1   308     228
381     sample p    219     538     2   308     227
380,381 079c1477    221     537     3   367,368,338     340,341,298
380,381 079c1477    221     536     4   367,368,338     339,342,283
380     e7181331    212     535     3   NULL    NULL
380     Sample p    198     534     1   NULL    NULL
380     079c1477    221     532     2   367,368,338     340,342,298
380     079c1477    221     531     1   338,367,368     283,340,341
380     079c1477    221     530     1   367,368,338     340,341,324
```

---

Comment: images have result set, i just need to merge red/green records too but also want to keep current group by

Comment: ohh sorry, then i need to format them as well, let me do it

Comment: So what happened when you grouped by product_id & product_option? PS What does "like this" mean? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: thanks, i need to use group by oo.order_product_id too otherwise its give unpredictable results

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your mind about results of that query. But, if you want get query results like this :

```html
380,381
```

```html
GROUP_CONCAT( orderid SEPARATOR ',' ) AS group_order_id,
```

Comment: thanks for your concern, i already use concat function but question is merging product with same option values

Comment: Please read what code snippets are for. These should be code blocks. See the edit help.